# Do not delete the mass-assignment tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The tag [mass-assignment](/questions/tagged/mass-assignment) has been included in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012, with the comment

> (not sure about this one, it seems strange and has a smell, please provide input)

Input [was provided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131519). Of course, since this was the 68th answer, it didn't receive much attention.

The tag wiki has no reservation anyway.

> DO NOT USE - Removed as part of "The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012" - See link in Tag Wiki for more information.

A simple [google search](http://google.com/search?q=%22mass+assignment%22) shows that this is a well-known programming concept, at least in the Ruby on Rails community; a perfectly cromulent tag. Please remove this tag from the cleanup list.

(I tried proposing a tag wiki. I'm not a RoR programmer nor more generally a web programmer, so if you're familiar with the concept, please improve.)

Comment: Can it at least be renamed to something less generic, like "rails-mass-assignment"?

Comment: @NicolBolas The phrase “mass assignment” is predominantly used by the RoR community, but it's also used outside, and the concept is generic (e.g. [1](http://freshbrewedcode.com/joshbush/2012/03/05/mass-assignment-aspnet-mvc/) in ASP.NET MVC, [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095634/php-active-record-update-relationships-via-mass-assignment) in PHP). So the tag name should remain framework-agnostic.

Comment: The problem is that, because the phrase is so generic, anyone who doesn't know what it's really referring to can use it incorrectly.

Comment: @NicolBolas Anyone can use a tag incorrectly, but I don't see any evidence of misuse of this tag. Has there been a posse on it recently? If (almost) no one is using the tag incorrectly (even though there was no tag wiki!), what's wrong with the tag?

Answer (score 2):

`mass assignment` is the term used to describe:

- The assigning of all attributes at once;
- Multiple variables getting assigned to the respective values on a
  single line.

Nowadays, the `mass assignment` feature is commonly known as [mass assignment vulnerabilities](http://blog.mhartl.com/2008/09/21/mass-assignment-in-rails-applications/), due to the harm that it brings to applications.

**Take the example of:** [GitHub user exploited a security vulnerability in the public key update](https://github.com/blog/1068-public-key-security-vulnerability-and-mitigation)

So, this term `mass assignment`, well known among **RoR** and **ASP.NET** programmers, proves to be useful in the current tag form, since it is a specific functionality and can also refer to the very problematic situations that comes with it.

**And so, I express my agreement to keep the tag as it is.**