# Tag links broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-links

I noticed that the tag link is not working in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134382/do-not-delete-the-mass-assignment-tag) for the [mass-assignment](/questions/tagged/mass-assignment) tag.  It redirects to a Meta Stack Exchange tag page, instead of the tag page for Stack Overflow.  I've tested with a bunch of other tag-links in the question preview, and they all redirect to Stack Overflow.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: Migrating the Q to MSO might be what's needed.

Comment: @Mat, I'm sure that would help, but there are other tag-links to SO that still work.  I've been testing and most work.

Comment: That post was edited recently (by Community). Just a guess, but maybe editing "fixes" the cached rendered version of the post. (i.e. they probably recently changed the tag link magic to point to MSE on MSE.)

Comment: @Mat, that sounds reasonable, but notice that the tag-link I put in my question also redirects incorrectly, so I guess the cache would have to be for specific tag-links, which sounds like a strange design.

Comment: I think it redirects correctly in your question. If you want to discuss one of Stack Overflow's tags, you'd be doing that on MSO now, not here.

Comment: @LanceRoberts the magic tag links were migrated yesterday. Do you have any examples of magic tag links still pointing to SO (from MSE)? There shouldn't be any...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228856/should-the-via-tag-be-burninated @m0sa

Comment: @m0sa, just create a question, then before putting it out, go to the preview and right-click to open in a new tab and you'll see they still work.

Comment: @Mat, good example.

Comment: Added a space, saved, and they are now pointing at MSE... as they should.

Comment: @Oded, yes, so here's what is happening that is a problem.  When you are creating a question, the magic tag-links in the preview still point to SO, then after you submit the question they point to MSE.  Can we get that fixed?

Comment: @Oded, I would argue that we should have some kind of mechanism to create magic tag-links to any site, but certainly it would be logical for SO to be the default.

Comment: You want them all to point at MSE, @Lance? Seeing as that is the correct behavior for MSE? The alternatives are to migrate or delete them.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - you seem to have missed the main reason for having a separate MSE. It is so SO **doesn't** have super special status.

Comment: @Oded, referencing my first reply to you, `fixed` in that context can be pointing to MSE, but it's broken behavior right now.

Comment: @Oded, in reference to pointing to SO, many, many posts will now be broken, some of which weren't really SO specific, they were just using an SO tag as an example.

Comment: the fact that they are pointing to SO in preview is still a bug though, fix incoming

Comment: @m0sa, ok, I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic tag links in markdown preview will be fixed in build rev `2014.4.24.2186` on meta.

> sites not affected, so no rev number this time